# How can you turn off the LEDs on a SparkFun AS7265x Spectral Triad (Spectroscopy Sensor)?

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I'm a newbie to program an Arduino but I need to turn off a LED from a external Spectroscopy Sensor.

This is the Sensor:

[image: sensor]

There are three LEDs on this sensor and they're turned on automatically when the Arduino is plugged in. Can someone perhaps explain in general how to address a LED mounted on something like that ?

Comment: it communicates over I2C (a.k.a. Wire or TwoWire). find a library, read the doc

Comment: @Juraj the leds communicate over i2c? I don't think they can be disabled, at least not via the bus because the IC on the top dorsn't look like a (suitable) uC to me.

Comment: `void enableBulb(uint8_t device);` `void setBulbCurrent(uint8_t current, uint8_t device);`

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/spectral-triad-as7265x-hookup-guide/all

Comment: Example 2 - Controlling the onboard LEDs

Comment: @SimSon, find a library, read the doc. why to guess?

Comment: @Juraj you're right. Now after *you* added a link to the datasheet, I see there are actually 5 leds on that board...

Comment: Thanks it worked :)